# C++ struct testing

Tags: c++, struct

Hi I am new to C++ and testing a structure in a c++ code in dev-c++. but it is not compiling and giving errors .
It is working well with .h extensions in pre-processor directives in dev-c++. so i Dont think so it carries .h extension problems

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
struct car
{
  const int MAX=10;
  char model[MAX];
  char spare_part[MAX];
  float cost;        

          }
int main()
{

    car BMW ;
    BMW.model[MAX]="SLR-8 S";
    BMW.spare_part[MAX]="SILENCER";
    BMW.cost=175.56F;


    cout << setw(50) << "\n\n WELCOME TO SHOWROOM" << endl << endl;
    cout <<  "CAR MODEL: " << BMW.model[MAX] << endl;
    cout << "SPARE PART: " << BMW.spare_part[MAX] << endl;
    cout << "COST OF PRODUCT: " << BMW.cost[MAX] << endl;  
    return 0;
    }
```

Compiler logs are:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp" -o "D:\cdev\projects\structure.exe"    -I"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"D:\cdev\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
In file included from D:/cdev/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,
             from D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:1:

D:/cdev/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:6: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member `MAX'

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:6: error: making `MAX' static

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:13: error: new types may not be defined in a return type

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:13: error: extraneous `int' ignored

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:13: error: `main' must return `int'

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp: In function `int main(...)':

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:16: error: `MAX' undeclared (first use this function)

D:\cdev\projects\structure.cpp:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only 
once for each function it appears in.)

Execution terminated
```

Comment: please include the error message in your post.

Comment: what error says? BTW, usually you write definitions in H files and actual code in c/cpp files

Comment: `BMW.model[MAX]="SLR-8 S";` is wrong, and MAX can't be index also

Comment: i have added compiler logs.

Comment: `char model[MAX];` is an array of `MAX` characters numbered from 0 to MAX-1. `BMW.model[MAX]="SLR-8 S";` tries to assign a whole string (or rather a const char*) to a single character one past the end of the array.

Comment: Not to mention `MAX` is not declared (you need to use `BMW.MAX` probably).

Comment: Standard headers don't have .h, drop conio.h, semi-colon after struct, you can't assign to an array, even if you could you are indexing out of the boundary of the array, setw works only for the next output operation... I'm gonna stop there, too many problems; you should start with a "hello world" and progress from there.

Comment: Start from the very first warning you've got. Read it. Try to understand what it says. Fix your code accordingly. Once you no longer get this warning, and only then, continue to fix everything else.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, you are not testing it - you are writing it.

Answer (score 2):

Values in stuct should be initialized in a constructor, or should be static. Like:

```
struct car
{
  static const int MAX=10;
  ...
```

There is a semicolon missing after the struct definition. It should be like:

```
struct car
{
  static const int MAX=10;
  char model[MAX];
  char spare_part[MAX];
  float cost;        

};
```

Comment: i would definitly like to increment you but I am not authorized. but it is much better way to explain then the rest of the above comments thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

Check your semicolons. One is required after the closing } of the struct.

Also, declare the MAX variable `static`, i.e.

```
{
    static const int MAX=10;
```

but the compiler tells you that one quite nicely...

And the third error comes from the fact that you declare `MAX` inside `car`, you'd have to reference it accordingly as `car::MAX`. But actually, the whole `BMW.model[MAX]="SLR-8 S";` statement doesn't really make sense. That would mean 'assign the string "SLR-8 S" to the character after the last one in BMW.model' (for a char[MAX], the valid indices start at 0, and go to (MAX-1)!). Best use `std::string` instead of `char model[MAX]`, that's by far easier to handle! E.g.:

```
struct car
{
    std::string model;
```

Then you can simply say

```
BMW.model="SLR-8 S";
```